# Limit a change to a maximum amount

Tags: c++, c

Say I have:

```
int currentVelocity; //can be negative
int targetVelocity; //can also be negative

void updateVelocity() // called every 100ms
{
   int limit = 5;
}
```

How can I get the velocity closer to the target velocity at each iteration with a maximum absolute change of 5?

Say my currentVelocity is -20 and target velocity is -26

My maximum absolute increase is 5.

When updateVelocity() is first called, currentVelocity becomes -25
when it is called again, currentVelocity is -26

and will be so forever unless target velocity changes.

What must be added to the update function to do this?

Thanks

Comment: @PawełStawarz The idea is that my updateVelocity function needs to change. It is incomplete.

Comment: I don't think this is an appropriate question... You directly ask for a piece of code.

Comment: What's so difficult about this question that made you post it here? This seems simple

Comment: @Filipe Gonçalve In an embedded environment, where no UB is allowed, this is not so trivial.  A simple `int delta = currentVelocity - targetVelocity` can easily overflow - not that OP may be concerned with that.

Comment: @chux Hum, good point. True, but seeing the accepted answer, I don't think he's concerned with overflow :p

Comment: @Filipe Gonçalve As the post mentioned "every 100ms" and "velocity", if this _is_ a real application, not paying attention to overflow is costly.  See a [US$ 370 million](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_(spacecraft)) one.

Comment: @chux hahahaha. Well, sh*t happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A straightforward way.

```
int currentVelocity; //can be negative
int targetVelocity; //can also be negative

void updateVelocity() // called every 100ms
{
   int limit = 5;
   int delta = targetVelocity - currentVelocity;

   if (delta > limit)
        currentVelocity += limit;
   else if (delta < -limit)
        currentVelocity -= limit;
   else
        currentVelocity = targetVelocity;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're trying to work with velocities as ints, but here you go.

```
int change_this_frame = targetVelocity - currentVelocity;

if( change_this_frame > 5 )
{
    change_this_frame = 5;
}

if( change_this_frame  < -5 )
{
    change_this_frame = -5;
}

currentVelocity += change_this_frame;
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of work to stay within INT_MIN and INT_MAX

```
#include <limits.h>
int currentVelocity; //can be negative
int targetVelocity; //c

void updateCurrentVelocity() // called every 100ms
{
   int limit = 5;
   int currentVelocityLimit;

   if (targetVelocity > currentVelocity) {
     if (currentVelocity <= INT_MAX - limit) {
       currentVelocityLimit = currentVelocity + limit;
     }
     else {
       currentVelocityLimit = INT_MAX;
     }
     if (currentVelocityLimit > targetVelocity) 
       currentVelocityLimit = targetVelocity;
     currentVelocity = currentVelocityLimit;
   }
   else if (targetVelocity < currentVelocity) {
     if (currentVelocity >= INT_MIN + limit) {
       currentVelocityLimit = currentVelocity - limit;
     }
     else {
       currentVelocityLimit = INT_MIN;
     }
     if (currentVelocityLimit < targetVelocity) 
       currentVelocityLimit = targetVelocity;
     currentVelocity = currentVelocityLimit;
   }
}
```

Comment: @OP, If you do not care about overflow, use Gassa solution.